# How to get and use proper signingKey for Azure Mobile Apps Authentication?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, jwt, azure-mobile-services, asp.net-core-middleware

I'm using the updated `Azure Mobile Apps` and the authentication providers like Google, Microsoft, Twitter, and Facebook for authenticating users to my website. All of this is working well and upon authenticating with my `Azure Mobile App` instance, I get back a valid `JWT` token representing the authenticated user. This token I'm turning around and sending as a `Authentication Bearer` token to the server to authenticate requests to another `ASP.NET Core` API service. All of this is working just fine.

The problem is getting the `JWT` validated on the server using the correct `signing key` value. For a test - if I take my `JWT` token to https://jwt.io/ *and* paste in my secret key from `Azure` using the correct algorithm `HS256` I still can't get past the "Invalid Signature" error. In the same area, if I call my `ASP.NET Core API` service which has `app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication` from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer` configured I get the same 401 error back from endpoints stating the following:

> 401 Unauthorized: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The
>   signature is invalid"

According to [Azure Mobile Apps offline WEBSITE_AUTH_SIGNING_KEY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35270361/azure-mobile-apps-offline-website-auth-signing-key/35272737) and some other sites I'm supposed to use the `WEBSITE_AUTH_SIGNING_KEY` from https://[Azure-Mobile-Site-Here].scm.azurewebsites.net/Env.cshtml I have gotten the value and tried to use it 10 ways from Sunday as the `IssuerSigningKey` on the server but to no success. I always get the same error.

Here is the configuration I have on the server. I've tried to narrow it down as much as possible, decompiling code and only turning on the minimum flags to validate. I can't get anything through.

```
private void ConfigureAuth(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    //Didn't work attempt #1
    //byte[] keyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("975BE84E150ABlahBlahBlahA2527E1AAC80606");
    //if (keyBytes.Length < 64)
    //{
    //    Array.Resize(ref keyBytes, 64);
    //}

    //Didn't work attempt #2
    //byte[] keyBytes = _UTF8Encoder.GetBytes("975BE84E150ABlahBlahBlahA2527E1AAC80606");

    //Didn't work attempt #3
    //var keyAsBytes = Convert.FromBase64String("975BE84E150ABlahBlahBlahA2527E1AAC80606");

    //Didn't work attempt #4
    //var signingKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("975BE84E150ABlahBlahBlahA2527E1AAC80606"));

    var signingKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(keyBytes);

    var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {

        RequireExpirationTime = false,
        RequireSignedTokens = false,
        SaveSigninToken = false,
        ValidateActor = false,
        ValidateAudience = false,
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateLifetime = false,

        //The signing key must match!
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = signingKey,
};

    app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
    {
        AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
        AutomaticChallenge = true,
        TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters
    });

}
```

As a note above, I've already tried making `ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false` to try and bypass this all and it didn't work. I still get the same error; it's like the bit didn't have an affect on the outcome.

I feel lost and guessing at this point as I'm not even sure that `WEBSITE_AUTH_SIGNING_KEY` is the correct `signingKey` and if it's not I'm spinning my wheels for nothing.

What is the proper `secret / signing key` used in generating the `JWT` token for an `Azure Mobile App` instance and how do I encorporate it correctly in the middleware configuration on the server to validate the token?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WEBSITE_AUTH_SIGNING_KEY is the appropriate environment variable / app setting.  However, it is encoded as a hex-string.  You need to decode it before use.  In the Node SDK, the code to do this is as follows:

```
function hexStringToBuffer(hexString) {
    var bytes = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < hexString.length; i += 2)
        bytes.push(parseInt(hexString.substr(i, 2), 16));
    return new Buffer(bytes);
}
```

You just need to convert this to C#.

Comment: Yes thank you!! I couldn't find out how it was encoded and hence the guessing. Thanks for the assist. C# code sample from here that works: http://stackoverflow.com/a/724905/410937